# Dropbox Java API with GWT Authentication problems

Tags: java, gwt, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using version 1.6 of the Dropbox API for Java found here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/java

I am also using GWT 2.5.1 in Eclipse 3.7

I have the following code which works when run as a Java Applcation:

```
    DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = new DbxRequestConfig(type, locale);
    DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);
    DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webauth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(requestConfig, appInfo);
    String result = webauth.start();
    System.out.println(result);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = reader.readLine();

    webauth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(requestConfig, appInfo);
    DbxAuthFinish finish = webauth.finish(code);

    DbxClient client = new DbxClient(requestConfig, finish.accessToken);
    DbxAccountInfo info = client.getAccountInfo();
    long total = info.quota.total;
    long used = info.quota.normal;

    System.out.println("total: " + total);
    System.out.println("used: " + used);
```

This works just fin when I run it as a Java Application. However, when I try to do something similar with GWT within a RemoteServiceServlet. I get an exception when I try to do

```
webauth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(requestConfig, appInfo);
```

The exception I am getting is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.prepRequest(StandardHttpRequestor.java:160)
at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:87)
at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:21)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPostNoAuth(DbxRequestUtil.java:156)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.doPostNoAuth(DbxRequestUtil.java:289)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxWebAuthHelper.finish(DbxWebAuthHelper.java:40)
at com.dropbox.core.DbxWebAuthNoRedirect.finish(DbxWebAuthNoRedirect.java:84)
at com.cloudshare.server.DropboxPlayground.getFinish(DropboxPlayground.java:21)
at com.cloudshare.server.DropboxServiceImpl.authenticate(DropboxServiceImpl.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
... 40 more
```

I have been banging my head against a wall for last couple of hours trying to figure out what is going on. I originally wanted to use a DbxWebAuth but the documentation in their API includes instructions that have classes that don't exist (I am assuming they did at one time).

I feel like the DbxWebAuthNoRedirect is doing something where it is dynamically loading a connection based on the classes that are available. But I have not been able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDITS:

Okay, so I looked at the Dropbox API source and the error is occurring here:

```
    URL urlObject = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection(this.proxy);
```

Because I am using Google App Engine, it is using its own URL object rather than the one imported by the App Engine API. Any ideas on a solution that doesn't involve writting a GWT wrapper for the Dropbox API.

Comment: Are you developing for google app engine? If so the class metioned in the error message `HttpsURLConnection` as used by the dropbox api isn't compatible with the app engine way of working. If you're not developing for app engine you need to disable app-engine.

Comment: I am using GAE. Any ideas on a work around?

Comment: On your edit. GAE internally creates a connector based on the url passed. However, since the dropbox api is a `https` url and therefor the dropbox api expects a secure connection class to be returned it casts it to that class. However GAE only supports `http` and will return a unsecure http connector which can't be cast to the secure connection class. Since the source code of the dropbox api is on github you could try changing the code into a unsecure object, but I don't know if this will work. (As a side note this is not a GWT problem, but a GAE problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use a secure `https://` url to connect? My guess is if you use a `http://` you get the unsecured connector that can't be cast to a secure connection.

**--edit--**

It looks the `HttpsURLConnection` class is simply not supported on GAE, therefor it will not work unlike the GAE documentation says. [Using HttpsURLConnection (doc issue)](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4645). This means you're probably out of luke using it directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not given an option for the type of request as I am using their API. I just call the finish method on an instance of `DbxWebAuthNoRedirect` which may be using http instead of an https. However, I am skeptical of this because it generates an https site to visit for authentication. Perhaps GWT is generating an http request instead of https? This would be surprising since I had no problems implementing the Google Drive API with GWT.

Comment: It looks like the Dropbox source is using Java's URL class which is changed on GAE. I think I may be able to modify the Dropbox source to fix this problem but I am not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: As of version 2.0.5 of the Dropbox SDK for Java, you can use [GoogleAppEngineHttpRequestor](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/http/GoogleAppEngineRequestor.html), which has explicit support for App Engine's URL Fetch API.

Answer (score 8):

Latest Dropbox SDK lets you choose a HttpRequestor implementation

`new DbxRequestConfig(APP_NAME, userLocale, HttpRequestor);`

So all you need to do is adapt the com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor to be Appengine friendly

Gist: [AppengineHttpRequestor.java](https://gist.github.com/radu-c/6630265)

Answer (score 1):

```
DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("107.108.85.10", 80));

StandardHttpRequestor requ = new StandardHttpRequestor(proxy);
DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",
Locale.getDefault().toString(),requ);
DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);
```

So by using `Proxy` (my firewall) in `StandardHttpRequestor` and using this requestor in `DbxRequestConfig` it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. As per this post, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/V8pREOXPX24,

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler 
$Connection extends the class java.net.HttpURLConnection
```

Hence I replaced the class

```
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

by

```
java.net.HttpURLConnection
```

in class com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor and rebuild the Dropbox Java SDK. Its working fine. A sample working app can be at https://gwt-gae-testing.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way to retrieve the access_token (but than i don't know how to handle the other method of Dropbox API).

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String code = req.getParameter("code");

    URL fetchurl = new URL(url);
    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(fetchurl, HTTPMethod.POST);
    String body = "code=" + code + "&grant_type=authorization_code" + "&client_id=" + dropboKey + "&client_secret=" + dropboxSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;
    request.setPayload(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);

    String respInJson = new String(response.getContent());

    LOGGER.warning(respInJson);

    JSONObject jsonObj;
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(respInJson);
        String uid=jsonObj.getString("uid");
        String access_token=jsonObj.getString("access_token");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I suggest changing HttpRequestor as @radu-c said. It works fine.